# Excel links to another workbook break after clicking Enable Editing

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook open which is linked to a separate excel workbook with no issues.  I then open the linked workbook however can’t edit it until I ‘enable editing’.  When I do this, the links in the first workbook (and all other workbooks in the chain) break – i.e. they say REF.

Comment: The second workbook probably has references to a book it can't find breaking all the original book's references.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.